# update Document verion name from google editor addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-workspace-add-ons

In our Google editor add-on, we export the existing document to be archived on our ECM system. When the document is saved on our Servers, is there a way to add a label on the version of the google document saved?

Comment: In what format is it exported in?

Comment: Do you mean when you open the document you want to see a label on the document as displayed? Or do you mean that when you are browsing your server? Are you able to post a screenshot with a example of how you want it to look?

Comment: It is exported as a Google Document and as a pdf. After it is exported, we need to display a label on our Google document stating this version is saved on our servers.
We need to display the same on the version tab.
Here is a link https://www.techrepublic.com/article/version-history-essentials-for-google-docs-sheets-and-slides/#:~:text=To%20name%20a%20file%20version,the%20name%2C%20then%20select%20Save.
We want to achieve this through the add-on using code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### There is a feature request for this

> https://issuetracker.google.com/147451299

Go give it a ☆ to let Google know that you would like this.

I'm afraid that the only way, at this time, to add a name to your version is manually.

Comment: Thank you. Starred for future reference!

Comment: Consider accepting this answer here on Stack so it serves for future reference (✓ button)

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom properties for the file as metadata via the Drive API. [See guide for details](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties).